# Two functions that coincide infinitely often

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Can you find two functions $f$ and $g$ defined on a closed interval $[a, b]$,  with real values,  such that $\exists (x_n) $ an infinite sequence of distinct points in $[a, b] $ such that $$\forall n, f(x_n) =g(x_n) $$ but $$f\neq g$$

**EDIT**: the question is not interesting as it is stated. I therefore require that $f$ or $g$ do not coincide on any interval.

I have an answer when they are defined on $\mathbb R$,  but in this case,  I can't find such.

Bonus point if you find some that are continuous,  or $C^n$ for large $n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f=0$ and $g=\exp(-1/|x|)\sin(1/x)$ (with $g(0)=0$) on $[-1,1]$. The sequence $(x_n)$ is of course that of the zeros $1/\pi n$ of $g$ in $(0,1]$. These form a discrete set (though not of course if one also throws in $0$).

Comment: I don't have any graph software available at the moment,  so how smooth is $g$?

Comment: It wiggles a lot, hence a good example.

Comment: I don't think graph software is very helpful in telling how smooth this function is. But I made it $\mathcal C^\infty$. (I'll make it an odd function around $0$ so that this makes sense easier at $0$). I is not real analytic at $0$ though.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**: The answer below is now obsolete now that the OP has edited the question.

Sure.  You can even define ones on $C^\infty$.  Take a look at the function:

> $$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}} & |x| < 1 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}$$

and let $g(x) = 0$.  $f(x) = g(x)$ everywhere except on the interval $(-1,1)$.  This is an example of a [bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

Restrict the domain to $[0,2]$, perhaps, and take the infinite series of points $( p_n )$ where $p_n$ is an enumeration of the rationals on $(1,2)$.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Comment: He asked for a function such that $f\not=g$ for every $x$ in domain

Comment: +1 And that's what he got. For $|x|<1$ there're not equal. There were no further restrictions on set where the functions are equal, in particular nothing about discretness. While this may not be quite what the OP *wanted*, that's definitely what he *asked* for.

Comment: Look at my edit,  I added an extra requirement.

Comment: @GabrielR. I see the extra requirement, and have edited the answer to note that the answer is now obsolete.